# Simple Android app to display CPU clock and CPU load

Tags: gratis, android, performance-analysis, system-monitor

I am looking for a very simple Android app that will display the CPU clock of each core and the current overall percentage of CPU load.  I want run this app on bootup to determine when the device is ***really*** done booting.

I have found all sorts of "almost, but not quite" apps, but they do too much or too little.

*Requirements:*

1. Android KitKat compatible
2. No permissions at all, except possibly "boot completed" (see Preference #2 below)
3. Free of charge (gratis)
4. Displays CPU clock of each core and the current overall percentage of CPU use on the main page of the app, all visible at once on a small screen
5. No ads
6. Does not establish any internet connections

*Preferences (none required):*

1. Has an option to run at boot time to display the data
2. Small apk size (this can be done in under 512KB!)
3. Open-source

Simple enough, right?  If you don't know of such an app, but want to write one, that works too!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I need the same (for a different purpose, though: I need to know if really all cores are used in specific situations). Had no time for a real check yet, so just a few pointers: my list of [System-Info Tools](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_systeminfo) e.g. mentions [TinyCore](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.neotech.app.tinycore) coming close to this (but double-size, it's 1M+ `.apk`). These two places might be a good starting point :)

Comment: Uh! [CPU Stats](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.takke.cpustats) comes real close – if a "n x 5" grid in the status bar is fine with you (n=# of cores). Only `BOOT_COMPLETED` permission, a little below 1M `.apk`. Well, instead of commenting here, I rather update that to my list unless I find a perfect match to post as answer :)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks.  I definitely don't want a status bar app; just want an app to display the info like any standard app, and then to be able to quickly close it when I'm done viewing the info.  But thank you for the suggestions :-)

Comment: (I use CPU Stats, nice app!)